# How Do I Query current ID against ID's in a collection to show only documents with similar fields and value using react Js and Firestore- Part 2

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

My goal for this was to fetch all documents that contain a field with the same value... The first time I run my application it shows all similar values from all documents in a collection against current ID, Here's the code:-

```js
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [dataSet, setDataSet] = useState({
        regNo: "",
    });

    const {userId}  = useParams();
    let id = userId

    useEffect(() => {
        let getUserDoc = async (id) => {
          let docRef = doc(db, `dentist/${id}`);
          let docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
          console.log('getUserDoc() received:', docSnap);
          if (docSnap.exists) {
            let theData = docSnap.data();
            console.log('getUserDoc() setting userInfo:', theData);
            setDataSet(theData);
          }
        }
      
        if (id) {
          getUserDoc(id);
          console.log("IdUser", id)
        } else {
          console.log('useEffect() -- no ID value');
        }
      }, [id]);
   
      let currentValue = dataSet.regNo
      console.log("currentvalue from doc", currentValue)

    useEffect(()=>{
        const getList = async () => {
            const collectionRef = collection(db, "dentist")
          const q = query(collectionRef, where("regNo", "==", currentValue))
          await getDocs(q).then((task)=>{
           let medData = task.docs.map((doc) => ({...doc.data(),
          id: doc.id}))
          setData(medData)
          console.log("medData", medData)
          }).catch((err) =>{
            console.log(err)
          })
        }
        getList()
      }, [])
```

This worked 100%, I could compare the regNo from the first document against all the documents in the collection, Here's my console log[image]

The challenge I'm facing now is when I refresh the page, the second useEffect returns 0 in the medData, that is, no document.. Here's my console:-
[image]

Once I refresh, the data I could see initially, disappears!

In addition, since I'm using async/await I chained everything together, at first I got all documents with similar value for regNo but when I refreshed, it all disappeared.. Here's the code:-

```js
   const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [dataSet, setDataSet] = useState({
        regNo: "",
    });

    const {userId}  = useParams();
    let id = userId

    let currentValue = dataSet.regNo
    console.log("currentvalue from doc", currentValue)

    useEffect(() => {
        let getUserDoc = async (id) => {
          let docRef = doc(db, `androcare/${id}`);
          let docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
          console.log('getUserDoc() received:', docSnap);
          if (docSnap.exists) {
            let theData = docSnap.data();
            console.log('getUserDoc() setting userInfo:', theData);
            setDataSet(theData);
          }
        }

        const getList = async () => {
            const collectionRef = collection(db, "androcare")
          const q = query(collectionRef, where("regNo", "==", currentValue))
          await getDocs(q).then((task)=>{
           let medData = task.docs.map((doc) => ({...doc.data(),
          id: doc.id}))
          setData(medData)
          console.log("medData", medData)
          }).catch((err) =>{
            console.log(err)
          })
        }
      
        if (id) {
          getUserDoc(id);
          console.log("IdUser", id)
          getList();
        } else {
          console.log('useEffect() -- no ID value');
        }
      }, [id]);
```

What I'm observing is upon refresh, it treats the regNo as an empty string, how I resolve this issue..

Comment: You should not put the code of the two queries (first the doc then the collection, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76478944/3371862) in two different useEffect blocks. Chain the two queries in the same block.

Comment: @Renaud Tarnec.. Kindly show working code, how I can chain this together.. I would really appreciate

Comment: I’m currently commuting and writing on a smartphone so I cannot share the full code, but since you use async/await it is quite easy. Get the `dentist/${id}` doc, get the regNo value and directly use it in the query with the `where` clause, all in the same coding block.

Comment: @Renaud Tarnec.. I would really appreciate if you'd share full working code from my code snippet

Comment: @Renaud Tarnec, I've chained both queries together and I still get the same issue, when I run the first time it returns the data, upon refresh it disappears, I've updated the code in the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not versed in react.js but I think that you should not put the code of the two queries (first the doc then the collection, as explained in my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76478944/3371862)) in two different `useEffect` blocks.

You should chain the two queries along the following lines (I let you integrate it in your react.js code, in a unique `useEffect` block):

```js
let id = userId;
let docRef = doc(db, `dentist/${id}`);
let docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
if (docSnap.exists) {
  setDataSet(theData);
  const theData = docSnap.data();
  const currentValue = theData.regNo;
  const collectionRef = collection(db, "dentist")
  const q = query(collectionRef, where("regNo", "==", currentValue))
  await getDocs(q).then((task)=>{
  let medData = task.docs.map((doc) => ({...doc.data(), id: doc.id}))
  setData(medData)
});
```